# Evaluate the integral $ \int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\frac 1{x^2}-2}}{x^5}\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt{x}}\:dx$ without substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

I think that from this conclusion I suppose I have done something wrong at algebraic modification or I have chosen the worst way around this integral, can someone help me

[image]

Comment: If you are supposed to solve this only by using your table of derivatives, you will need to furnish that table as well, right?

Comment: Note that $x^2+x^{-2}-2=(x-x^{-1})^2$. Then we are down to powers of $x$.

Comment: so the whole expression becomes x+x^(-1) ?

Comment: I had a typo (minus sign, fixed). Actually things are a little complicated. But for example take $x\gt 1$. Then the square root is $x-x^{-1}$. When you multiply by the other stuff, you get something of shape $x^a-x^b$. I think $a=-7/2$.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that we need to be careful about $\sqrt$, because it is $x-x^{-1}$ for $x\ge 1$, and is $-(x-x^{-1})$ for $0\lt x\lt 1$.

Comment: $x^2-2+x^{-2}=(x-x^{-1})^2$ and $\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt x}=\sqrt x$. Hence your integrand is $\pm(x^{-7/2}-x^{-11/2}).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that
$$
x^2+\frac 1{x^2}-2=\left(x-\frac 1x\right)^2
$$ then
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\frac 1{x^2}-2}}{x^5}\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt{x}}=\left|x-\frac 1x\right|x^{-
9/2}$$ and the evaluation is straightforward on appropriate intervals.

For example, for $x \geq 1$, you have
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\frac 1{x^2}-2}}{x^5}\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt{x}}\:dx=\int\left(x-\frac 1x\right)x^{-9/2}dx=\int x^{-7/2}dx-\int x^{-11/2}dx$$